# Linux TCP_NODELAY on the receiver side

Tags: linux, tcp

I have an application that reads packets from a device using TCP. I am wondering if my receiver application creates sockets using TCP_NODELAY option, will the device automatically start sending packets without buffering them, or do I have to make this change on the sender(device)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting TCP_NODELAY only affects the timing of sends. It has no effect on incoming information.

However, I should point out that most people who feel like they need to set TCP_NODELAY for some reason are doing the wrong thing. Unless you have no control over the protocol and the protocol wasn't designed to be used over TCP, using TCP_NODELAY is probably the wrong thing to do. TCP_NODELAY, like keepalives, exists to allow protocols not designed to work over TCP to do so a little bit less badly. If that doesn't describe your situation, it's the wrong solution.

Comment: I am trying to create a very low latency system, that my desirable in my case. My question was actually this: can I control timing of sends of server, by creating socket on the receiver with TCP_NODELAY flag, will the sender automatically adapt to TCP_NODELAY without having to change firmware.